# How to add a line to a file in discord.js?

Tags: writefile, node.js-fs

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.content.startsWith("+" + "sell")) {
      let sells = fs.readFileSync('sells.txt', 'utf8')
     let args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);;
     const link = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    let sell = link + "\n" + sells
      fs.writeFileSync("sells.txt", JSON.stringify(sell, 0));
  }});
```

This is my code.
I want that I run the command `+sell <customer-id> <product>` that in the sells.txt file is in line 1 => User#1234 | Product xyz
in line 2 then => User#1314 | Product abc

Thanks!

This is my code.
I want that I run the command `+sell <customer-id> <product>` that in the sells.txt file is in line 1 => User#1234 | Product xyz
in line 2 then => User#1314 | Product abc